# Tensorflow: adapting Tensor shape to a batch of data

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to make a deep nn, really similar to the one that tensorflow gives in its tutorial but mine is in 1d (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#build-a-multilayer-convolutional-network) however I'm receiving this message

> Input to reshape is a tensor with 6000 values, but the requested shape
>   has 30

It has sense, since I'm not providing just 30 values (corresponding to one sequence of data) but 200 times 30. And here is where my doubt comes: I saw that the operations in the tutorial are applied without taking care of how big the batch is, and I tried to imitate the tutorial the most I could, so where is the failure?

To solve the problem, I thought that I should change the way data is presented, but I'm giving a couple of 2d numpy.arrays (one for input data and another one for labels) the same as it's being given in the MNist tutorial. My code is [here](https://github.com/dialgop/small_deep_nn)

I'm sure that my failure is in the way the data is structured (maybe I'm tired, I don't know) but if someone could help me, that would be awesome.

Comment: Try changing `tf.reshape(x, [1,shpeData,1])` to `tf.reshape(x, [-1,shpeData,1])`?

Comment: Thanks @sygi, I was going to write that I had solved it with the -1, but you already said it.